# ¿Qué significa tener un tipo de dato de objeto entre paréntesis, delante de otro objeto?

Tags: java

Estoy viendo este tema, y si bien puedo ejecutarlo normalmente copiando el código, no entiendo la sintaxis y la lógica de la siguiente línea. He buscado respuestas pero solo encuentro cómo escribir código y no la explicación del mismo. Copio código desde el constructor para no hacerlo tan largo.

```
public Formulario() {
        setLayout(null);
        combo1=new JComboBox();
        combo1.setBounds(10,10,80,20);
        add(combo1);
        combo1.addItem("rojo");
        combo1.addItem("vede");
        combo1.addItem("azul");
        combo1.addItem("amarillo");
        combo1.addItem("negro");
        combo1.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==combo1) {
  String seleccionado=(String)combo1.getSelectedItem(); //ESTA LINEA NO ENTIENDO 
            setTitle(seleccionado);
        }
    }
```

Lo que no entiendo es qué hace ese paréntesis `(String)` adelante del objeto `combo1`. El tutorial que estoy viendo no lo explica y nunca había visto una sintaxis parecida hasta ahora. ¿Qué significa y para qué está?

Perdón si resulta rara la pregunta, pero desde el punto de vista lógico, me parece redundante (ya que entiendo que no se puede cargar `int` en el `JComboBox`) y desde el punto de vista sintáctico es la primera vez que veo que se pone un paréntesis delante. Ya que dudo que se trate de un capricho, supongo que tiene una explicación.

Comment: ¿Has intentado buscar más fuentes para capacitarte? Respondiendo a tu pregunta, eso es un "casteo", casting en inglés

Comment: Es una conversión de tipos que en Java llamamos CASTEO, mira [aquí](https://javadesdecero.es/basico/conversion-tipo-ejemplos-casting/) si quieres algo de información sobre ese tema. Pero esto es algo basico de Java, poquito sabes de ese lenguaje si no has visto eso antes. Te recomiendo un buen libro sobre Java para no ir tan perdido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El método `getSelectedItem()` devuelve un dato de tipo `Object`, por lo mismo la variable `seleccionado` que es de tipo `String`, no podría tomar este dato, para ello se debe de hacer una **refundición** o (como es mayormente conocido) **casteo**, que básicamente consiste en convertir un tipo de objeto en otro.

También se podría usar:

```
String seleccionado = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

---

Existen dos tipos de casteos:

*Implícitos:*

- Cuando se coloca un valor pequeño en un contenedor grande, **no es necesario** poner `(<Tipo de dato>) <valor>`

```java
//variable de tipo int con valor 10
int numeroEntero = 10;
//variable de tipo Long y se le asigna la variable de tipo int
long numeroLargo = numeroEntero;
```

*Explícitos:*

- Cuando se coloca un valor grande en un contenedor pequeño, **es necesario** poner `(<Tipo de dato>) <valor>`

```java
//variable de tipo int con valor 10
int numeroEntero = 10;
//variable de tipo short y se le asigna la variable de tipo int
short numeroCorto = (short)numeroEntero;
```

Para saber cual usar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente:
[¿Qué es y para que sirve el Casting?](http://sistemate.net/web/blog/home/-/blogs/casting-y-herencia;jsessionid=625E6291B7F35AE4DF9612C4FABB0260?controlPanelCategory=portlet_58)

Comment: +1 Por la dedicación y empeño en dar una respuesta clara.

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente, me gustaría ponerte en contexto: si miras la documentación del control JComboBox (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), verás que el método `getSelectedItem()` devuelve un valor de tipo **Object**. Con esto en mente, no puedes acceder a lo que esta representando un tipo **Object** ya que *es demasiado generico*, por ello, se realiza un **"casting"** a un **String** usando el operador () antes de una sentencia, es decir, se convierte el Object y accede con la estructura de un objeto **String**. Esto se hace porque cada elemento que se ha añadido al *JComboBox* es una **String** *(puedes verlo en cada linea `combo1.addItem()`)*, por lo que se sabe de antemano el tipo de los elementos del *JComboBox*. Espero haberme explicado.

Un saludo.